# getting image from OpenFileDialog and convert it to ::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, visual-studio-2015

i want to get image path from OpenFileDialog and read read this image with cv::imread ,i use this code :

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(openFileDialog1->FileName)
```

but i get this error :

> no suitable constructor exists to convert from "System::String ^" to "cv::String"

please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

It is because `cv::string` and `system::string` aren't the same type. Though you can, however, probably convert between them manually.

as the `cv::string` class has a constructor that accepts a stl `std::string` class, you can try to convert your `system::string` to a `std::string` and then use that as input for imread.

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d8f/classcv_1_1String.html#aba22f87619091a1b6a2899d0b45a3472